# Issue with logic and Loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, logic, controls

I started coding small program in Java. I wanted to exercise try-catch block, but i did not even come to that part and got stuck on loop part. I know this is very basic loop issue, but i guess i caught myself in a very simple logical problem. What I need from this program is if a user press 1, then to jump to switch statement and execute proper case. If a user press anything but 1 or 2, to go back to the MenuLoop function and execute it again until pressed correct number (1 or 2). I used While loop for control. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TryCatchExercise {

    public static void MenuLoop() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;

    System.out.println("1. Check for Number 1");
    System.out.println("2. Check for Number 2");
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice... ");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    while (choice != 1 || choice != 2) {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
        MenuLoop();
    }    //Isn't it logical at this point for loop to be skipped and 
         // go to Switch if a user pressed 1 or 2.??

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Pressed 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Pressed 2");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MenuLoop();

}

}
 OUTPUT
 1. Check for Number 1
 2. Check for Number 2
 Please enter your choice... 1
 Invalid entry, press 1 or 2
 1. Check for Number 1
 2. Check for Number 2
 Please enter your choice... 2
 Invalid entry, press 1 or 2
 1. Check for Number 1
 2. Check for Number 2
 Please enter your choice... 5
 Invalid entry, press 1 or 2
 1. Check for Number 1
 2. Check for Number 2
 Please enter your choice...
```

Comment: `choice != 1 || choice != 2` is always true. `&&` maybe?

Comment: That worked. So, if user did not press 1 and did not press 2, then out of loop. If it was user did not press 1 or user did not press 2, loop is true, otherwise it's false.

Answer (score 1):

You need a logical and (not or) here

```
while (choice != 1 || choice != 2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
    MenuLoop();
}
```

should be something like

```
while (choice != 1 && choice != 2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
    MenuLoop();
}
```

**or** (using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) like

```
while (!(choice == 1 || choice == 2)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
    MenuLoop();
}
```

Comment: Right. In both cases AND or De Morgan's laws worked. I messed up on boolean when they were always true.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you are recursively calling `menuLoop` from within `menuLoop`

If you had a while loop within `main` then you could just do a return if the proper keys is not pressed.

so main would be something like

```
while (!menuLoop () {
  System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
}
```

and `menuLoop` would return a boolean

```
public static boolean MenuLoop() {

  ....

System.out.println("1. Check for Number 1");
System.out.println("2. Check for Number 2");
System.out.print("Please enter your choice... ");
choice = input.nextInt();
if(choice != 1 && choice != 2) {   // and NOT or
    return false;
}    

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    System.out.println("Pressed 1");
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("Pressed 2");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
}
return true;
```

Also please remember that the `scanner.nextInt` will not swallow up the `Enter` that may or may not be pressed.

Comment: I see. So as long the loop is false in main function, repeat that function until returns true in switch statement.

Comment: If i keep calling menuLoop from menuLoop it would give ok result, as long as it is && and not ||. Is that something that would slow down performance of the program if the program has many other methods or many lines of codes? Or that is something it is not generally usable in programming?

Comment: In your simplistic case, there is not too much of a problem, but generally it is a good idea to split input processing from logic processing.

Comment: Right. I have to work more on that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code. In your code , it's not need to use iteration.

```
choice = input.nextInt();
while (choice != 1 && choice != 2) {
    System.out.println("Invalid entry, press 1 or 2");
    choice = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aaric, that was definitely the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a logical problem, the "choice" value should be either 1 or 2.
In your (while) statement you are checking that "choice" is not different from 1
but also that "choice" is not different from 2. This condition is never reached because "choice" can be either 1 or 2 but not both values at the same time. This is only an explanation of the situation.

Comment: I see what you mean. There are 2 values to be checked, and checked only one, should be both checked, not one or the other.